# Compiling class with package

Tags: java, compilation, directory, package

Please tell me how would the class in following directory structure compile.

Default classpath is-

/foo

This is the directory structure-

```
foo 

  | 
  test

     | 
     xcom

        |--A.class

        |--B.java
```

These are two files-

```
package xcom; 
public class A{} 

package xcom; 
public class B extends A{}
```

Which allows B.java to compile?

A. Set current directory to xcom then invoke

javac B.java

B. Set current directory to xcom then invoke

javac -classpath . B.java

C. Set current directory to test then invoke

javac -classpath . xcom/B.java

Now my query is-

Why A nad B are wrong and C is correct?

Comment: Are you sure C is correct ?

Comment: C should read: Set current directory to **test** then invoke, and yes it is correct

Comment: I typed xcom by mistake. Now corrected it.

Comment: @Astha: If any of the answers helped you solve your problem, please mark it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily. For the same reason, if you where able to find a solution yourself, please post your own answer and mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since classes `A` and `B` belong to package `xcom` (see `package xcom;` at the top of the files), the java compiler expects to find them inside a folder names "xcom" and it expects to find that folder in the classpath (actually in the sourcepath, which when not specified is the same as the classpath).

You can find more detailed information in the **[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)**.

### Short explanation:

**Why is 1st answer wrong ?**
`A. Set current directory to xcom then invoke: javac B.java`
javac expects a folder "xcom" inside the classpath (which is currently set to "/foo"). But there is no such folder, so it fails to locate class `B`.

**Why is 12nd answer wrong ?**
`B. Set current directory to xcom then invoke: javac -classpath . B.java`
Specifying `-classpath .` designates the current directory (namely "xcom") as the classpath. javac expects a folder "xcom" inside the classpath (which is currently set to "/foo/test/xcom"). But there is no such folder, so it fails to locate class `B`.

**Why is the 3rd answer correct ?**
`C. Set current directory to test then invoke: javac -classpath . xcom/B.java`
Specifying `-classpath .` designates the current directory (namely "test") as the classpath. javac expects a folder "xcom" inside the classpath (which is currently set to "/foo/test") and it finds indeed such a folder. Then javac expects the source file for class B to be in that "xcom" folder and indeed it finds it, and compiles it and class B is been executed happily ever after.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.
Is there any way of compilation if I put class A without package and class B with package like this-

class A-

public class A{} 

class B-

package xcom; 
public class B extends A{}

Comment: Possibly, but why on earth do you want to do that ? What would be the point ? Besides, it is a really bad practice to not use a package for your apps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think C is correct.**Set current directory to test then invoke** ,  then the class B will compile.